# How to make NVD3 charts responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts, nvd3.js

I am working with NVD3 and having some trouble with the responsiveness of the charts.

So far, I've managed to create several charts but these always overflow the container, causing the yAxis labels to be cut or the xAxis extremities to be cut.

Here's an image of one of the charts, in which the yAxis is cut:

[image]

These are the code snippets I'm using to create the chart:

```js
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(false);

  if (data.hasOwnProperty("key") && isColumnTotalChart || isRowTotalChart) {
    chart.xAxis
      .axisLabel(data.chartDataset.key);
  }

  chart.xAxis.tickValues(data.chartLabelIndexes)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return data.chartLabels[d];
    });

  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

  if (chartData.labels.length > 10) {
    chart.xAxis.rotateLabels(-90);
  }

  chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(true);

  d3.selectAll(chartSelectedSvg + " > *").remove();

  d3.select(chartSelectedSvg)
    .datum(data.chartDataset)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

```css
div>svg {
  min-height: 30vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div ng-show="chartColumnData.data.length !== 0">
  <div id="chartTotalColumns" ng-show="chartColumnData.data.length !== 0">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-padding layout-align="center center" ng-show="chartColumnData.data.length !== 0">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to set the **viewBox** and **preserveAspectRatio** properties of the SVG, but to no avail.

I have also unsuccessfully tried what is suggested in these questions:

[Responsive pie chart using NVD3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625038/responsive-pie-chart-using-nvd3)

[NVD3 Chart responsive issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445128/nvd3-chart-responsive-issue)

[How to make a <svg> element expand or contract to its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919076/how-to-make-a-svg-element-expand-or-contract-to-its-parent-container)

Do you have any suggestion as to how to make these charts responsive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this:

[Y axis label not displaying large numbers - Multi-Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297393/y-axis-label-not-displaying-large-numbers-multi-bar-chart)

I have managed to figure it out: simply adjusting the margins solves the problem.

[According to the documentation](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#multiBarHorizontalChart), to adjust all chart margins, you'll have to use this line of code:

`chart.margin({"left":5,"right":5,"top":10,"bottom":10})`

If you only need to set one margin, then you'll have to do:

`chart.margin().left = 50;`

Now the chart looks like this:
[image]